# Brownie Contract Interaction

Tags: ether, ganache, brownie

If I deploy open auction contract on ganache with brownie, how can I send a bid into the contract with a brownie command?

**>>> Openauction[0].bid(Wei(1e18))** is giving me an error, how can I send eth to a function with no parameters?

Getting this error:

File "brownie/convert/normalize.py", line 15, in format_input
raise TypeError(f"{abi['name']} requires no arguments")
TypeError: bid requires no arguments

```
@public
@payable
def bid():
# Check if bidding period is over.
assert block.timestamp < self.auctionEnd
# Check if bid is high enough
assert msg.value > self.highestBid
# Track the refund for the previous high bidder
self.pendingReturns[self.highestBidder] += self.highestBid
# Track new high bid
self.highestBidder = msg.sender
self.highestBid = msg.value
```

full contract source: https://kauri.io/#collections/Getting%20Started/an-introduction-to-smart-contracts-with-vyper/#introductory-open-auction-example

I appreciate any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Openauction[0].bid({'from':accounts[0], 'amount': 1e18})